# Spring Data Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a Mongo DB - Spring Data Document named **Archive** with the properties **iucId** and **storageDateTime**. Now I will query for the latest stored Archive with a specific iucId. I have no idea how to ask about the latest **storageDateTime**.

Ask about iucId is easy:

```
List<Archive> findArchiveByIucId(final String iucId);
```

but the record with the latest **storageDateTime** is my problem.

Could anyone help me concerning this issue?
Thanks a lot for help!!

```
@Document(collection = "Archive")
public class Archive {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String iucId
    private DateTime storageDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Optional<Archive> findFirstByIucIdOrderByStorageDateTimeDesc(final String iucId);
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

Comment: In current Spring Data versions instead of `Archive` it might be better to use `Optional<Archive>`. This gives an opportunity to operate on optional (and thus use Java 8 features) instead of doing nullchecks.

Answer (score 0):

The following mongodb query will return the latest stored Archive with a specific iucId:

```
//The '-1' = sort descending (newest to oldest)
db.archive.find({iucId: "zzz"}).sort({storageDateTime: -1}).limit(1);
```

In Spring data, use this :

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

    //...
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("iucId").is("zzz"));
    query.limit(1);
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "storageDateTime"));

    mongoOperation.find(query, Domain.class);
```